# Angular Routing not working on Windows 8 Metro APP

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

I am trying to create Windows 8 Metro App using JavaScript (AngularJS). I am using Visual Studio 2013 for development on Windows 8.1 OS.

I have two controllers and two templates and configured a route for each of these templates.

I have tried using jQuery 1.8.2 and jQuery 2.03, AngularJS 1.2.1 and angular-route.js 1.2.1 etc.

Routing is not working and templates are not getting loaded as I navigate a different view.

To cross check, I created an Empty MVC web app and tested the same configuration/code. It was working fine with no issues. As I navigate through different routes, templates are loaded properly.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

use jquery 1.8 patched for windows 8, look at this : http://www.incloud.de/2012/08/windows-8-using-jquery-for-app-development/